# MPAndroidChart-BarChart,the following is detailed description

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

mpandroidchart for my project,I want to the result just like the below image.I meet some question have long time. The first I want show the data is 11.23% ,but the project show 11.2% for me ,I can't find any way to change it ,please help me .The second I want to the legend is like the below image,but the legent of mpandroidchart-barchar no have description, how can I do? The third question is that I want to change y axis like the below image, I don't know if it realize?

![I want image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuXhb.png

![My image now]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG9FB.png
public class BarChartActivity extends Activity {

```
private BarChart barChart;
private BarData data;
private BarDataSet dataSet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bar_chart);
    barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

    barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false); // 隐藏右边的y轴
    barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    barChart.setGridBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // 设置背景色
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false); // 隐藏网格竖线
    YAxis yAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft(); // 得到y轴坐标
    yAxis.setStartAtZero(false); // y轴是否从0开始

    yAxis.mAxisMinimum = -20f;
    yAxis.setLabelCount(10); // x轴横线的条数
    yAxis.setAxisMinValue(-100f); // 设置最小值
    yAxis.setAxisMaxValue(99f);
    // yAxis.setSpaceTop(100);
    // yAxis.setSpaceBottom(-100);
    // barChart.setVisibleYRange(50f,null);
    // barChart.getXAxis().enableGridDashedLine(400, 50, 0);
    // barChart.getAxisLeft().resetAxisMaxValue(); //自动调整y轴的最大值
    // legend.setLabels(new String[]{"你好","我好","大家好"});
    barChart.getLegendRenderer();
    barChart.getXAxis().setAxisLineColor(Color.BLUE); // 设置x轴线的颜色
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisLineColor(Color.GREEN); // 设置y轴线的颜色
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setGridColor(Color.RED); // x轴线的颜色
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setGridLineWidth(1f); // x轴网格线的宽度
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setSpaceTop(150f);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(Color.RED);// y坐标轴的上的刻度文字的颜色

    // List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    // list.add("你好");
    // list.add("你好1");
    // list.add("你好2");
    // barChart.getLegend().setLabels(list);

    Legend legend = barChart.getLegend();
    legend.setXEntrySpace(5f);
    legend.setYEntrySpace(20f);

    barChart.getXAxis().setSpaceBetweenLabels(5);
    barChart.getXAxis().setYOffset(2f);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());

    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();// 显示的条目
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>(); // 横坐标标签

    float[] yValues = getYValues(90.23f, -2.84f, 9.21f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        entries.add(new BarEntry(yValues[i], i));
        xVals.add(""); // 可以从这里取消x轴的坐标
    }

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.rgb(90, 147, 229),
            Color.rgb(247, 183, 48), Color.rgb(245, 70, 70) };
    dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, ""); // 原来是公司你利润报表
    dataSet.setColors(colors);
    dataSet.setBarSpacePercent(70f); // 设置柱子的宽度
    dataSet.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter()); // 设置柱子上的数字百分数显示
    dataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLUE); // 柱子上数字的颜色
    data = new BarData(xVals, dataSet);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.animateY(3000);
    barChart.setDescription("");// 公司前半年财务报表(单位：万元)
    barChart.getLegend().setPosition(LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_CENTER); // 设置图例在正下方
    barChart.getLegend().setStackSpace(50f); // 设置图例之间的距离
    dataSet.setValueTextSize(28); // 设置柱子上数字的大小

}

public float[] getYValues(float x, float y, float z) {
    return new float[] { x, y, z };
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the image? Post your code too

Comment: I english is not good, I have post my image , and the code please wait for a moment,

Answer (score 1):

For number format you set [ValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface).

You can set Legend property like Style color, font etc using [Legend](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend).

To change Y axis negative use setStartAtZero(false);

Comment: I have try " dataSet.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter()); " but it only keep one data after point,I want double-digit behind of point.you don't understand exactly what I mean

Comment: Can you write DecimalFormat here ?